# Ansible Unable to Ping

Tags: ansible, junos-automation

I am trying to teach myself ansible, and I'm struggling to get things working properly. I currently have a lab spun up on Eve-NG so I can play around with some stuff before I start using this on a live network. The IP of the host (a virtual Juniper MX) that I am trying to reach is 10.6.0.250. My inventory file is named lab_inventoy.yml and the contents are as follows:

```
all:
  hosts:
    vMX-1:
      ansible_user: mschmidt
      ansible_port: 22
      ansible_host: 10.6.0.250
```

I am trying to run the ping module to verify I can SSH to the virtual MX. I run the following command: `ansible -i ./lab_inventory.yml all -k -m ping` but I am getting this error.

```
vMX-1 | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    }, 
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.6.0.250 closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "\r\nerror: unknown command: /bin/sh\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
    "rc": 0
```

I have been trying to find the source of the issue for quite some time now with no luck. I have very little programing or scripting experience so this is all very new to me. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This probably what you're looking for: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/junos_ping_module.html

Answer (score 0):

how about using `wait for`

```yaml
tasks: 
    - name: Checking NETCONF connectivity
      wait_for: 
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}" 
        port: 830 or 22 (as per requirement)   
        timeout: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

ansible -i ./lab_inventory.yml all -k -m ping -c local